# gcloud compute command to know current zone of machine

Tags: cloud, gcloud, zone

I need help in google cloud , I am doing 1 application using google cloud. in google cloud I have 1 instance of windows and google cloud sdk on that. I need one command which will return zone name of that instance.
Note -
I don't need zone list.
I need only that zone name where my instance is running.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14):

tl;dr:

```
gcloud compute instances list <your instance name> --format 'csv[no-heading](zone)'
```

. . .

This is doing two things.  The

```
gcloud compute instances list your-instance-name
```

part lists all instances with that name, e.g.

```
NAME                ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE INTERNAL_IP    EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
your-instance-name  europe-west1-c n1-standard-1             1.000.000.001 100.000.000.01 RUNNING
```

And the

```
--format 'csv[no-heading](zone)'
```

part reformats the output to be a table with with headers and only the `zone` column.  See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats (or `gcloud help topic formats`) for more information about formatting output.

Comment: `list name` is deprecated and `--format` may be simplified: `gcloud compute instances list --filter="name=('your-hostname')" --format "value(zone)"`

Comment: tks @xmedeko, the `--format "value(zone)"` is very useful

Answer (score 3):

If on the instance itself and you want to get the zone:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="name=('`hostname`')" --format 'csv[no-heading](zone)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeffrey's answer is spot on for using the gcloud command line tool. If you'd rather use the GoogleCloud PowerShell module, the following will get you the uri of the zone:

```
$zone = (Get-GCEInstance).Where({$_.Name -eq $(hostname)}).Zone
```

e.g. this might populate $zone with:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-001/zones/us-east1-a
```

If you just need the end section (and annoyingly, parameters on other cmdlets seem to require only the end section and the uri is not a valid format), you can do:

```
$zone.Substring($zone.LastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

to return:

```
us-east1-a
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some sort of URL-fetching tool like cURL, you can get the zone name like this:

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone -H Metadata-Flavor:Google | cut '-d/' -f4
```